# Is there a way to execute multiple sql statements using the **same** sysdate?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a program which executes sql statements.  Within a transaction, I'd like to update several tables using the **same** sysdate.
eg. (run the following 3 statements in a transaction)

```
update table1 set some_col = 'updated' where some_other_col < sysdate;
delete from table2 where some_col < sysdate;
insert into table3 (col1, col2) select c1, c2 from table4 where some_col < sysdate;
```

If these 3 statements are executed in a transaction, the "sysdate" each one is using will be whatever timestamp we are at currently as this statement is running, not at the start of the transaction.

I *could* create a stored procedure and initially select the sysdate into a variable, using PL/SQL, but I'd prefer to just run sql statements from an external program.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Each query would have a slightly different datetime for sysdate the wa you are doing it above.  I think you will need to make that stored proc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I could create a stored procedure and
>   initially select the sysdate into a
>   variable, using PL/SQL, but I'd prefer
>   to just run sql statements from an
>   external program

Use an anonymous block instead of a stored procedure, something like (untested):

```
declare
  v_sysdate date := sysdate;
begin
  update table1 set some_col = 'updated' where some_other_col < v_sysdate;
  delete from table2 where some_col < v_sysdate;
  insert into table3 (col1, col2) select c1, c2 from table4 where some_col < v_sysdate;
  commit;
exception
  when others then 
  rollback;
  raise;
end;
```

Comment: You can run/execute this just like regular sql (ie. from an external program)?

Comment: ...I don't believe there's any difference between this and a stored procedure - other than it's not stored...it's still PL/SQL, not SQL, and can't be run (directly) by an external program

Comment: there are plenty of differences between a stored procedure and an anonymous block.  What "external program" cannot run this directly (but can run individual DML statements)?

Comment: Wow! Much to my surprise this worked!  I never realized you could execute PL/SQL this way!  This opens up a whole new world!  Thanks bunches!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's working as it's supposed to, the time is recalculated with each query. Just store the timestamp in a variable in your program, and use that variable in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Which external program? If you are using SQL*Plus, this would work:

```
var d char(50)
begin select sysdate into :d from dual; end;
/

update table1 set some_col = 'updated' where some_other_col < :d;
delete from table2 where some_col < :d;
insert into table3 (col1, col2) select c1, c2 from table4 where some_col < :d;
```

You might have to adjust your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting for the session...